# Access installed client certificate on client machine, for TLS handshake with server golang

Tags: ssl, go, keychain

I have a golang APP, which is supposed to get few contents from a Server(HTTPS). during TLS handshakes how should i get the installed client certs from the system(keychain for example on Mac). How would i prompt to user when there are two certificate installed for same server?

Comment: The term "client certificate" usually refers to a certificate that the client presents to the server to authenticate itself, as an alternative for username/password for instance. Is that really what you mean?

Comment: You can't. You specify the certificate to use in your code. During the protocol exchange there is no time (or even a method) available to wait for user input.

Comment: Yes @peter thats what i mean.